# Review marker not resetting

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, notifications

On this site, in the top of the page there is an option for a red markers, next to the word review, which should show how many posts are waiting for your review.

On TSE, when under 10K rep, the warner showed how many post were waiting in the suggested edits queue and that worked well. Only tag edits I had waiting for others gave a false message.

When reaching 10K, the marker shows up for all posts in all the review queues, and it does not reset/disappear when I do reviews. Often it shows a wrong number for hours.

When working well it is a useful feature that reminds you to check the review queues, but when stuck it is useless.

[image: detail of a scrreenshot with the marker but no waiting posts to be reviewed]
*I have taken a screenshot, with the marker showing top right.*
Photo can be used under creative commons rules, photo by Willeke.

Comment: That number shows the cumulative number of reviews to be completed across the entire site. In other words it's telling you that X posts on Travel need review. Once you complete your reviews the site might still have posts awaiting review by other users. Hence why sometimes the notification remains. It's a great way to know if the site is falling behind in its review tasks.

Comment: So it is designed to be useless for normal users. I can not see which posts are still waiting for others, as that does is not shown to me. Nor can I do anything about them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a feature and not a bug. [**The review counter shows every pending review, regardless of whether you completed it already or not.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251659/what-does-the-number-next-to-the-review-link-in-the-top-bar-actually-mean) Say for example you just voted to close a question and that question still has close votes missing. The item is still pending review by others and will therefore still show up in the counter.

Whilst I find it useful to know whether the site is falling back on its review tasks, others find it useless. [The word on the Meta is thought that making that a personalised counter for each user is too much of a hard task.](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/294/13657) There have been talks of changing this but as of now the status is unknown.

[This SEDE query I edited from rene's original](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/489432/show-details-of-pending-and-completed-reviews) shows the details of the pending and completed review items. You can use it to figure out which tasks are affecting the counter.

Comment: They may call it a feature, I still see it as a bug. Just one we will have to live with for now. Hopefully someone will be able to design a useful 'need review' marker some time soon.

Comment: Colour can differ between different screens. But what I mean is that I have no reviews in the queues, all available, and there is a 5 in the marker next to the word 'review'. In other words, it does not tell you when you need to do something but when someone needs to do something.